# System of equations and distinct result sets

Tags: equation-solving

Question on the below system of equations:

First off, in section 1 below, I had to manually play with that 4th parameter (300) so I can finally see that there are actually 96 sets of solutions. Is there a way that I do not provide that and Mathematica tells me there are 96? If I remove the parameter I only get 1 set. As I increase it, I eventually see that beyond 96, no matter how high I go it stops at 96.

Second, in section 2 below, I see the CountDistinct gives me the total number of sets. But if you pay attention there are only 4 unique sets (3,21,27,29), (9,11,27,33), (7,13,29,31), (11,13,19,37) - But there are 24 permutations for each set, since the 4 vars are interchangeable, hence 24*4=96 total).
How can I ask Mathematica to also list these 4 unique sets?

```
eqn = FullSimplify[{w + x + y + z == 80, w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 2020}]
```

1. 

```
Table[FindInstance[eqn, {w, x, y, z}, Integers, 300] ]

{{w -> 3, x -> 21, y -> 27, z -> 29}, {w -> 3, x -> 21, y -> 29, 
  z -> 27}, {w -> 3, x -> 27, y -> 21, z -> 29}, {w -> 3, x -> 27, 
  y -> 29, z -> 21}, {w -> 3, x -> 29, y -> 21, z -> 27}, {w -> 3, 
  x -> 29, y -> 27, z -> 21}, {w -> 7, x -> 13, y -> 29, 
  z -> 31}, {w -> 7, x -> 13, y -> 31, z -> 29}, {w -> 7, x -> 29, 
  y -> 13, z -> 31}, {w -> 7, x -> 29, y -> 31, z -> 13}, {w -> 7, 
  x -> 31, y -> 13, z -> 29}, {w -> 7, x -> 31, y -> 29, 
  z -> 13}, {w -> 9, x -> 11, y -> 27, z -> 33}, {w -> 9, x -> 11, 
  y -> 33, z -> 27}, {w -> 9, x -> 27, y -> 11, z -> 33}, {w -> 9, 
  x -> 27, y -> 33, z -> 11}, .....
...(snip)....
  {w -> 33, x -> 27, y -> 9, z -> 11}, {w -> 33, x -> 27, y -> 11, 
  z -> 9}, {w -> 37, x -> 11, y -> 13, z -> 19}, {w -> 37, x -> 11, 
  y -> 19, z -> 13}, {w -> 37, x -> 13, y -> 11, z -> 19}, {w -> 37, 
  x -> 13, y -> 19, z -> 11}, {w -> 37, x -> 19, y -> 11, 
  z -> 13}, {w -> 37, x -> 19, y -> 13, z -> 11}}
```

2. 

```
CountDistinct[Table[FindInstance[eqn, {w, x, y, z}, Integers, 300] ]]

{96, 4}
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that Solve and Reduce have been mentioned already in the previous answers. Expanding on LouisB's answer, here is another method that would get you the unique sets:

```
In[71]:= DeleteDuplicates[Sort[#] & /@ Values[sols]]

Out[71]= {{3, 21, 27, 29}, {7, 13, 29, 31}, {9, 11, 27, 33}, {11, 13, 19, 37}}
```

However, I should mention that `DeleteDuplicates` is computaionally more expensive than `Select`.

Comment: Thanks to all 3 of you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Reduce[{w + x + y + z == 80, 
  w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 2020}, PositiveIntegers]
%//Length
```

> `96`

```
Reduce[{w + x + y + z == 80, w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 2020, 
  w >= x >= y >= z}, PositiveIntegers]
% // Length
```

> `4`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Solve` to get all of the solutions and `Length` to count the number of solutions.

```
eqn = FullSimplify[{w + x + y + z == 80, 
                    w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 2020}]

soln = Solve[eqn, {w, x, y, z}, Integers];

Length@soln   (*  96  *)
```

To see the unique sets, look for the sets that are sorted (ordered), like this

```
Select[Values@soln, OrderedQ]

(*  {{3, 21, 27, 29}, {7, 13, 29, 31}, 
     {9, 11, 27, 33}, {11, 13, 19, 37}}  *)
```

If you only want the four ordered sets, add that constraint to your equations like this

```
eqn = {w + x + y + z == 80,
   w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 2020,
   w <= x <= y <= z};

soln = Solve[eqn, {w, x, y, z}, Integers];

Length@soln  (*  4  *)
```